# Relative layout on the bottom hides the layout in the middle for the equivalent height at the bottom . My XML is as below:

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/activity_header_background">

        <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/help_faq_menu">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/faq_header">

        <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        </ProgressBar>
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/activity_footer_background"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_drawable_shape"
        android:text="@string/done">
        </Button>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_drawable_shape"
        android:text="@string/contact_support">
        </Button>

        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@null">
        </ImageButton>  
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is as "header" is at top then comes the relative layout "body" and then "footer". evrything is fine except the relative layout "footer" hides 50dip of the "body" part at the bottom.

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/body" give in footer Relativelayout

Comment: @Abhi ...thanks for the suggetion. android:layout_below for "footer" didn't fix this but android:layout_above="@+id/footer" for the "body" did worked well.

Comment: body is in framelayout, why dont you use relativelayout instead and fix the height how much you want

Comment: hey use android:layout_above="@+id/footer" in body layout

Comment: yes Abhi, i got it right. Thanks for your suggestion. it was very quick..

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_below="@+id/body" give in footer Relativelayout
```

`android:layout_above="@+id/footer"` in body layout

and  body is in framelayout, why dont you use relativelayout instead and fix the height how much you want.